# cell looping for data values

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheet1 full of football results.

```
Season------Home-------Away---------Score  
2009--------Albion------Burton--------0-1  
2011--------Albion------Burton--------2-1  
2012--------Albion------Burton--------4-0
```

I want to produce sheet2 same workbook, for each teams history. 
Each cell (r1,c1) must be referenced for it's data value, then manipulated into sheet2 by placing the score into the correct season column. Then looped for the next teams history Etc.

Sheet2

```
Home--------Away----2000-2001-2002-2003-2004-2005-2006-2007-2008-2009-2010-2011-2012  
Albion------Burton------------------------------------------------0-1-------2-1--4-0
```

Can someone start me off using Excel2010 vba please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can help you get started.

With `Sheet.Cells(Row, Col)` you can access any cell you like.

With `For... Next` loop you can loop trough the rows and columns using nested loops.

You can access both sheets by their name, by default `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

You can also use `Range` objects to find data in sheets more efficiently;

```
Dim r As Range
Dim m As Range

Set r = Sheet2.Range("A1:G1") ' For the row with all your years
Set m = r.Find(Value1) ' Value1 could be the year

If Not m Is Nothing Then
    ' It was found and m.Column tells which column it is, yay!
End If
```

Etc... stackoverflow is also littered with basic questions like how to do stuff like this, feel free to search. Who knows you might encounter a problem with question never encountered before!

Comment: Looks good. I will give it a go and look at them Set and Find commands. Cheers

Comment: Soory for the late reply - I took your advice, It was pretty much what I thought too. Couldn't get the hang of Range. So I delved back into my days when I learnt BASIC on the Specky and Amy. Using Worksheets("year").Cells(x, y) and IF THEN FOR Next Loops to checked the data. I managed to place the data into my other worksheet as I wanted. Over 16,000 entries compiled,sorted, Etc in less than 2 seconds. Cheers